# Increase the api limit in ggmap's geocode function (in R)

Tags: r, google-maps, google-maps-api-2, geocode, ggmap

I'm trying to use the `geocode` function from the `ggmaps` library in `R` to get coordinates for specific locations. I'm able to use the function fine so far.

The issue I'm running into is that I would like to increase my daily limit from `2,500` to `100,000`. The official Google [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/usage-limits)
says that this is readily possible if you enable billing on the project, which I'm happy to do. When you proceed with this process, the `Google Developers Console` gives you a personalized API key.

However, the `geocode` function doesn't have an option to put in this personalized API key. Instead, it asks for the `client` (client ID for business users) and `signature`(signature for business users), which is how [Google Maps API for Work](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/business/) customers can access the API. I get that this is also an option, but that seems to be a very use case, since Google Maps API for Work seems to be designed for large enterprise accounts:

> Daily quota starting at 100,000 requests per 24 hours, based on annual contractual purchase.

So my question boils down to this: can I use the `geocode` function from the `ggmaps`library in `R` to ping the Google Maps Geocoding API?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I didn't find a way to use the existing `geocode` function (from the `ggmap` library) to answer this question, so I just created a new function to just do this myself using the existing `getURL` function (from the `RCurl` library) and the `fromJSON` function (from the `RJSONIO` library).

Write the new function:

```
library(RJSONIO)
library(RCurl)

getGeoData <- function(location){
  location <- gsub(' ','+',location)
  geo_data <- getURL(paste("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=",location,"&key=**[YOUR GOOGLE API KEY HERE]**", sep=""))
  raw_data_2 <- fromJSON(geo_data)
  return(raw_data_2)
}
```

Test:
`getGeoData("San Francisco")`

This gives you a list with the same data that's almost (but not quite) in the same exact format as the list produced by `geocode("San Francisco")`.

Answer (score 14):

I've written the package [**googleway**](https://github.com/SymbolixAU/googleway) to access google maps API where you can specify your api key.

For example

```
library(googleway)

key <- "your_api_key"

google_geocode(address = "San Francisco",
               key = key)

# $results
# address_components
# 1 San Francisco, San Francisco County, California, United States, SF, San Francisco County, CA, US, locality, political, administrative_area_level_2, political, administrative_area_level_1, political, country, political
# formatted_address geometry.bounds.northeast.lat geometry.bounds.northeast.lng geometry.bounds.southwest.lat
# 1 San Francisco, CA, USA                      37.92977                     -122.3279                      37.69313
# geometry.bounds.southwest.lng geometry.location.lat geometry.location.lng geometry.location_type
# 1                     -123.1661              37.77493             -122.4194            APPROXIMATE
# geometry.viewport.northeast.lat geometry.viewport.northeast.lng geometry.viewport.southwest.lat
# 1                          37.812                       -122.3482                         37.7034
# geometry.viewport.southwest.lng                    place_id               types
# 1                        -122.527 ChIJIQBpAG2ahYAR_6128GcTUEo locality, political
# 
# $status
# [1] "OK"
```

Answer (score 14):

With `ggmap` version 2.7 or greater (as of 13 Dec, not yet available on Cran, but you can install with `devtools::install_github("dkahle/ggmap")`, you simply need to run  `register_google(key = 'LONG KEY STRING')` and then you can call any of the ggmap functions such as `geocode` or `mutate_geocode` and use your API key.

Comment: Its Mar 2018, and 2.7 still not in CRAN. ;(

Comment: @yuk October 2018 now, still not in CRAN, and now `geocode` doesn't work at all without an API key: `Keyless access to Google Maps Platform is deprecated. Please use an API key with all your API calls to avoid service interruption. For further details please refer to http://g.co/dev/maps-no-account`

Answer (score 6):

Thanks for this! It helped me along immensely.
Your solution is pretty specific, so I wanted to include the adaptations I made of your function. It threw bugs because `raw_data` and `geo_data_list` are undefined. I'm guessing these were specific to your local environment.

For me, inputting a location and returning the lat, lon worked with this:

```
 getGeoData <- function(location, api_key){
  location <- gsub(' ','+',location)
  geo_data <- getURL(paste("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=",location,sprintf("&key=%s",api_key), sep=""))
  geo_data <- fromJSON(geo_data)
  return(geo_data$results[[1]]$geometry$location)
}
```

You can modify the return statement to index into `geo_data` to get different properties other than lat lon too.

Hope this helps someone.

R