# Geocode failed with status OVER_QUERY_LIMIT R studio

Tags: r, google-geocoder, google-geocoding-api

Apologies for repeating a question, but I've haven't been able to fix the problem with the answers I found. I'm working with transport-workshop.Rmd from this repo: https://github.com/nickbearman/transport-workshop. The first 3 queries I make with qmap work no problem `qmap('Leeds')`, `qmap('LS2 9JT')` and `qmap('LS2 9JT', zoom = 17)`. But then I go on with the workshop and try `qmap('LS2 9JT', zoom = 17, maptype = 'satellite')`, which returns me this error:

`geocode failed with status OVER_QUERY_LIMIT, location = "LS2 9JT"Error in data.frame(ll.lat = ll[1], ll.lon = ll[2], ur.lat = ur[1], ur.lon = ur[2]) : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 0, 1`

When checking:
`> geocodeQueryCheck()
2495 geocoding queries remaining.`

Found that specifying a Google Maps API key may sort it out: 
`devtools::install_github("dkahle/ggmap")`
`register_google(key = "my_api_key")` from https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/get-api-key , but I keep getting the same error. Not sure what else to check or try.

Working with R version 3.4.3 (2017-11-30), Windows 10.

Comment: a similar [question is here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34402979/5977215)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There can be two reasons for this :

1) You may have exceeded a `24-hour limit` if you are using free version of google API. You can either go for premium service or check the limit policy for service which you are using [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/premium/previous-licenses/articles/usage-limits)

2) You are crossing limit of `requests per second` by hitting geocode  multiple times in one second . So you can change your code and add the wait time before next request to avoid this error.

Answer (score 2):

I also had the same problem again and again. If you are running multiple queries in a loop you can insert a pause like `Sys.sleep(5)`.

But from my experience, for all the Google related queries, I found the package `googleway` much better than `ggmap`. Maybe you try this? Note: here you will need a key, which you will easily get after registering at Google.

Answer (score 2):

I have had this experience too. Sometimes even the helpful fixes proposed by Rohan Kadu and DatamineR don't fix the problem (though I haven't tried `googleway`).

You might also try changing the ggmap source to "dsk" for Data Science Toolkit like this:

```
result <- geocode(df$Address, output = "latlona", source = "dsk")
```

This has worked for me. (Though `dsk` has a few limitations. Have a look at the `ggmap` documentation.)

Good luck.